# Message.Body - Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format

Tags: c#, msmq

While creating a new 'transactional' queue, I first need to find if any 'non transactional' `MessageQueue` with the same name exists or not. If one does, I need to copy messages from old queue to new transactional queue.

To achieve this (when I find old queue with the same name):
1. I am creating a temporary queue (which I found being created as Transactional by default).
2. I am looping through messages from old queue and sending them to new queue.
3. Deleting the old queue
4. Creating new transactional queue.
5. looping through messages from temporary transactional queue and sending them to new queue.
6. Deleting the temporary queue

The messages are sent from old queue to new queue without any exception. However when I try to read the message body as message.Body

> Body = 'message.Body' threw an
>   exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   Cannot deserialize the message passed
>   as an argument. Cannot recognize the
>   serialization format

How can I achieve the mentioned requirement and what would be going wrong in my approach?

I am quite new to MSMQ. 
(Using Windows XP, Visual Studio 2008, .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 2):

You are not "looping through messages from old queue and sending them to new queue".
You are instead creating new messages using the data from the old messages.

So if you start with a "good" message, it doesn't mean you will end up with the same.
The important information is what:

1. What code was used to create the original message
2. What code is used to create the new message in temp queue
3. What code is used to create the new message in final queue
4. What code is used to read the message from the final queue

I am expecting either that the messages are not being recreated in the same way or the receiving process is not reading them in the right way. That is, which message formatter did you use? ActiveX, for example?

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: I really appreciate your analysis of the problem and I upvoted too since it's going to be useful someone who is facing this problem. All the questions you have raised are very valid in the case mentioned in original question. However, even after taking care of all these things, somehow I am getting the same exceptions sometimes, not always!

Comment: Is this a problem where the message body is good but an exception is raised. Or is the message body corrupted and so cannot be read? Do you get the exception when reading a message from either queues or just the temp queue?